# ModelForm and ModelSelect2Widget (django-select2)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-select2

I have a ModelForm which includes a ModelSelect2Widget from django-select2

https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2

Following the Documentation from here:

https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2Widget

**forms.py**

```
class RentalForm(forms.ModelForm):


    name = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
                model=ldap_data,
                search_fields=['user__icontains']
            )
        )
    date_start = forms.CharField(label="Datum Ausleihe", help_text="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder': '01.01.2019' }))
    date_end = forms.CharField(label="Datum Rückgabe", help_text="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder': '01.01.2019' }))

    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ['device', 'name', 'date_start', 'date_end',]
```

**models.py**

```
class ldap_data(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

ldap_data contains around 100 entries.

In my opinion everything looks fine, but in the rendered template no data is available in the `name` dropdown.

Console Log in Google Chrome shows:

```
select2.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at select2.min.js:1
    at select2.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ select2.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ select2.min.js:1
django_select2.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at django_select2.js:9
    at django_select2.js:11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

{{ form.media.js }}

needs to be after the import of jquery.

Answer (score 5):

Did you follow all the steps in the [getting started section](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html#quick-start)?

> 1. Add django_select2 to your INSTALLED_APPS in your project settings.
> 2. Add django_select to your urlconf if you use any ModelWidgets:
>
>    ```
>    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
>    ```
> 3. Add the CSS to the head of your Django template:
>
>    ```
>    {{ form.media.css }}
>    ```
> 4. Add the JavaScript to the end of the body of your Django template:
>
>    ```
>    {{ form.media.js }}
>    ```

Also, there appears to be an external dependency not provided by the module itself:

> External Dependencies
>
> jQuery version 2 This is not included in the
>   package since it is expected that in most scenarios this would already
>   be available.

Comment: Yes, everything is included.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it happens to me too recently... And turns out that the jquery script

`(<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>)`

should be placed first before any scripts that use jquery (it will use jquery, but the jquery hasn't been called).